# Ansible: Jinja2 template test both a variable is defined and not empty

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a variable, let call it value1, and a Jinja2 template. The Jinja2 template includes the following line:

```
LINE=” This string must be included this string is optional= {{ value1}}”
```

What I need to implement: If value1 is defined with a string – let assume that the string is OK  (Value1: OK), the file should be

```
LINE=” This string must be included this string is optional= OK”
```

If value1 is not defined (empty Value1: ), the file should be

```
LINE=” This string must be included”
```

So how the Jinja2 should be configured?

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"**If value1 is not defined (empty Value1: ), the file should be LINE=” This string must be included”**"*

A: Test the variable is both defined and not empty, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat test.txt.j2
{% if value1 is defined and value1|d('')|length > 0 %}
LINE=” This string must be included this string is optional= {{ value1 }}”
{% else %}
LINE=” This string must be included”
{% endif %}
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - template:
        dest: test.txt
        src: test.txt.j2
```

Running the playbook without *value1* defined or with empty *value1*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e value1=''
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat test.txt
LINE=” This string must be included”
```

When the variable is both defined and not empty, e.g.

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e value1=OK
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat test.txt
LINE=” This string must be included this string is optional= OK”
```